# how to add postgres-configuration into cordas build gradle deployNodes-task

Tags: postgresql, gradle, corda

i want to replace in the build-gradle task `deployNodes` the configuration for the default h2-database to a postgres implementation

i want to replace the entry `h2Port 10013`

with

```
dataSourceProperties: {
    dataSourceClassName: "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource",
    dataSource.url: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres_xyz?currentSchema=public",
    dataSource.user: "xyz",
    dataSource.password: "xyz",
    dataSource.currentSchema: "public"
}
database: {
    transactionIsolationLevel: "READ_COMMITTED"
}
```

how can i do this / which format can i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can add the Postgresql DB properties to your node config in `build.gradle` script using `extraConfig=[ ... ]` block is shown as below.

```
node {

    ...

    extraConfig = [
        dataSourceProperties: [
                dataSourceClassName : "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource",
                'dataSource.url' : "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/nodedb",
                'dataSource.user' : "postgres",
                'dataSource.password' : "pa$$w0rd"
        ],
        database: [
                transactionIsolationLevel : "READ_COMMITTED"
        ]
    ]
}
```